# Memory management issue with AssetsLibrary framework

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My code take a lot time to load images from gallery. I store url of each image in database and then load them from gallery using AssetsLibrary framework. But i notice that it take more memory and so that i receive memory warning. after some time app is crash down. Here i put my code.

```
-(void) nextImageLoad
{
//    ALAssetsLibrary* self. assetslibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    self.myScrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
    NSLog(@"current :- %d, loaded_photo :- %d, [imageData count] :- %d",current, loaded_photo, [imageData count]);

    if(current>loaded_photo && current < [imageData count])
    {
        ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
        {
            self.rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
            CGImageRef iref = [self.rep fullResolutionImage];
            if (iref) 
            {

                UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.x, y, 300, 300)];
                temp.image=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];     

                [self.myScrollView addSubview:temp];
                [temp release];


                [myScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.x+600, 410)];
                [myScrollView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

            }
            else
            {

            }
        };

        ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
        {
            NSLog(@"booya, cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
        };

        [self.assetslibrary assetForURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.imageData objectAtIndex:current] valueForKey:@"photo_url"] ]
                       resultBlock:resultblock
                      failureBlock:failureblock];
         self.x=self.x+320;
        loaded_photo= loaded_photo+1;
    }



}

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
}
-(void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.x)
    {        
        NSLog(@"left");   
        if(current>0)
        current=current-1;
    }
    else if (lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.x) 
    {
        NSLog(@"right");
        current=current+1;
        [self nextImageLoad];        

    }
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to know if this is the problem, but try creating an autorelease pool inside all your blocks:

```
block = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

  // rest of block here

  [pool release];
}
```

Also remember if you return early inside the block, you need to release the pool object before your return statement.

Comment: i also facing the same issue, i tried  NSAutoreleasePool but done't work its get crease at the after loading 107 images.

Comment: @SmartWork you should post your code as a new question. Unless you have turned ARC on you do need to an autorelease pool as I demonstrated in this answer.